# Exit when Cursor%not found Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Hi guys I have a pl/sql statement which is supposed to fetch data from one table to another through a cursor but some fields are empty and am thinking that is why it is exiting the line

```
exit when cursor%not found;
```

I have googled around and I have seen the suggestion to use the line after fetch statement but that seems to be the case when You have two cursors but in Mycase I have one cursor. Please some one help me tune up this query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure TBAADM.MIGR_EIT
AS
CURSOR cur_eit  IS SELECT entity_id, nrml_accrued_amount_cr,nrml_accrued_amount_dr,   nrml_booked_amount_cr, nrml_booked_amount_dr, nrml_interest_amount_cr,
nrml_interest_amount_dr,
next_int_run_date_cr ,next_int_run_date_dr ,interest_calc_upto_date_cr,   interest_calc_upto_date_dr,xfer_min_bal
,xfer_min_bal_date, booked_upto_date_cr,booked_upto_date_dr FROM TBAADM.eit_temp  ;
tempeit1  TBAADM.EIT%ROWTYPE;
number_of_rows_updated number;
BEGIN
number_of_rows_updated:=0;

update tbaadm.eit_temp set entity_id=(select gam.acid from tbaadm.gam where gam.foracid=eit_temp.act_num);

OPEN cur_eit;

LOOP
FETCH cur_eit INTO  tempeit1.entity_id,tempeit1.nrml_accrued_amount_cr,tempeit1.nrml_accrued_amount_dr,tempeit1    .nrml_booked_amount_cr,tempeit1.nrml_booked_amount_dr,
tempeit1.nrml_interest_amount_cr, tempeit1.nrml_interest_amount_dr,
tempeit1.next_int_run_date_cr ,tempeit1.next_int_run_date_dr  ,tempeit1.interest_calc_upto_date_cr,  tempeit1.interest_calc_upto_date_dr,tempeit1.xfer_min_bal
,tempeit1.xfer_min_bal_date, tempeit1.booked_upto_date_cr,tempeit1.booked_upto_date_dr;
exit when cur_eit%notfound;
```

Comment: Anyone? who can help me out here?

Comment: throw in  'dbms_output.put_line( 'tempeit1.entity_id =>' ||  tempeit1.entity_id  );' after the **exit when** statement to see where it fails.  is it possible to simply ditch the opening of the cursor and simply rewrite the transformation to be done in a query? Also, if you are using SQL Developer you can debug it as well.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to be able to really help you. Your speculation that "some fields are empty and am thinking that is why it is exiting the line" is definitely wrong -- `EXIT WHEN cur_eit%NOTFOUND` won't be fooled by null values in the fetched record -- but there's no way for anyone *here* to be able to tell what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit cursors are not required (and IMHO advisible) anymore since Oracle 8. I'd rewrite your code to use an implicit cursor in a `FOR ... LOOP`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tbaadm.migr_eit
AS
  number_of_rows_updated   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  number_of_rows_updated := 0;

  UPDATE tbaadm.eit_temp
     SET entity_id =
           (SELECT gam.acid
              FROM tbaadm.gam
             WHERE gam.foracid = eit_temp.act_num);

  FOR tempeit1 IN (SELECT entity_id
                         ,nrml_accrued_amount_cr
                         ,nrml_accrued_amount_dr
                         ,nrml_booked_amount_cr
                         ,nrml_booked_amount_dr
                         ,nrml_interest_amount_cr
                         ,nrml_interest_amount_dr
                         ,next_int_run_date_cr
                         ,next_int_run_date_dr
                         ,interest_calc_upto_date_cr
                         ,interest_calc_upto_date_dr
                         ,xfer_min_bal
                         ,xfer_min_bal_date
                         ,booked_upto_date_cr
                         ,booked_upto_date_dr
                     FROM tbaadm.eit_temp)
  LOOP
    /* do what ever you need to do with 
      tempeit1.entity_id,tempeit1.nrml_accrued_amount_cr,tempeit1.nrml_accrued_amount_dr,tempeit1    .nrml_booked_amount_cr,tempeit1.nrml_booked_amount_dr,
      tempeit1.nrml_interest_amount_cr, tempeit1.nrml_interest_amount_dr,
      tempeit1.next_int_run_date_cr ,tempeit1.next_int_run_date_dr  ,tempeit1.interest_calc_upto_date_cr,  tempeit1.interest_calc_upto_date_dr,tempeit1.xfer_min_bal
      ,tempeit1.xfer_min_bal_date, tempeit1.booked_upto_date_cr,tempeit1.booked_upto_date_dr;
    */
    NULL; -- do something useful
  END LOOP;
```